ViewModel initialisation when the factory is no longer there
I am creating a minimal ViewModel in my MainActivity, using the by viewModels  mechanism.
It currently just maintains a repository, by Dependency Injection.
This requires construction parameters, so I provided a factory class for doing this.
I instantiate a Factory object within MainActivity and pass same using by viewModels to initialise the first and only instance of that ViewModel.
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("settings")

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

//..
    private val viewModel : AutomationViewModel by viewModels {
        AutomationViewModelFactory(
        this.application, SettingsRepository(dataStore))
    }
//...

The ViewModel looks like this:
class AutomationViewModel(
    private val mApplication: Application, // not really needed.
    private val repository: SettingsRepository
): ViewModel() {

    // example property to setup an observable state
    val loginParametersState: StateFlow<LoginParameters> =
        repository.LoginParametersFlow.stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.Eagerly, LoginParameters()
        )

    // This is the dummy method, that seems to be necessary to 
    //    preheat.
    var dummy: Int = 0; private set
    fun setDummy(x: Int) {
        dummy = x
    }

}

And here is the associated Factory class
class AutomationViewModelFactory(
    private val mApplication: Application, // not really needed
    private val repository: SettingsRepository
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return when(modelClass) {
            AutomationViewModel::class.java -> AutomationViewModel(mApplication, repository)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        } as T
    }

// Not sure what this is about
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>, extras: CreationExtras): T {
        return super.create(modelClass, extras)
    }

That AutomationViewModel is then used in one of my Fragments, also using the by viewModels mechanism. The idea is, of course, that I take advantage of the previously cached instance of the already-instantiated AutomationViewModel.
On my Fragments, I get hold of the ViewModel object using the same 'by' mechanism.
However, I don't pass the Factory object in at this point, because it's out of scope now, being scoped to the Activity.
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
    private val connector: AutomationViewModel by activityViewModels()

    //.. Usual boilerplate code for onCreate, onCreateView, onViewCreated. Nothing particular to see there.


    }

In any case, I don't want to use the factory object in the Fragment because I don't have access to it, and don't want to end up coupling into the Fragment all the stuff that is managed by MainActivity, and I am expecting to use an already cached VM instance.
However, this doesn't work. My Factory object never gets instantiated; the default factory is used instead, and throws an exception because it knows not how to instantiate my particular ViewModel class.
I discovered that the VM was actually never getting instantiated in MainActivity because it is, currently, not touched by it.
It appears that the VM's instantiation is being deferred until the Fragment where, as I said above, the Factory is no longer available.
Is my understanding of what is going on here correct?
Is my structure of passing the Factory into the by statement in the Activity only, just using the naked by to instantiate(retrieve cached) in the Fragments, correct ?
I have noticed that I can make it all work by simply having a dummy function on my VM, which does nothing but causes it to be 'preheated' by forcing instantion at that point in MyActivity.
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //.. boilerplate from Wizard

        // Seems to work, only if I add this below, which does 
        //   nothing
        viewModel.setDummy(1)

    }
}

All of the other posts I have seen say the the by and get mechanisms are interchangeable.
This is my main question:
Is there truly no way to instantiate a VM eagerly ?
Should I be using a dummy preheat method as a permanent solution.
This is the post from which I am mainly working

Hey, you had lot of text, but the question you are asking is not clear. Can you be more specific with the question. However, based on what I understand The ViewModelFactory should be singleton and can be used by both activity and fragment. That way the VM will be initlised in activity scoped, whenever its invoked from Fragment.

"That ViewModel is then used in some of my Fragments, also using the 'by viewModels' mechanism." - please show that code. Maybe you need to use activityViewModels instead.

Sorry about the heavy text. I was composing on my phone. The point of my question is "How to instantiate a ViewModel which requires a Factory class, if the lazy evaluation means that it doesn't get instantiated until it's too late?" I've added code, and am indeed using activityViewModels. This doesn't help, however,  because I still have no idea whether the VM will be instantiated before any Fragment is. I would logically have to pass that Factory object to each and every Fragment on the off-chance that /that/ fragment happens to be the one that causes lazy instantiation to actually happen.

@Saran Sankaran. That was my understanding too, that the VM gets initialised in the context of the Activity, when it is first invoked by any Fragment. This however, doesn't appear to be the case: If the VM doesn't get 'really' initialised in the Activity, the initialisation then happens for the first time in the Fragment, but the lazy eval that was setup in the Activity seems to lose its factory parameter: it just gets instantiated for the first time in the Fragment without any factory object.

viewModels returns a Lazy object, which explains the behavior you're seeing.

by viewModels() returns Lazy so it will only be initialized when it is first used, in your case the fragment. You can manually initialize the ViewModel in your MainActivity.onCreate() using ViewModelProvider.
MainActivity.kt
private lateinit viewModel: AutomationViewModel

override fun onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(...)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        AutomationViewModelFactory(this.application, SettingsRepository(dataStore))
    )

by viewModels() also uses ViewModelProvider, but since it is lazy it is not initialized until you first use it.

So the action of 'manually' initialising is different from the 'by' method? I was led to believe that they were just syntactic sugar for each other, both being lazy. I will try the manual initialisation in my activity but use the 'by' method in those fragments which use it (and whose behaviour is predicated on its preexistence). I think I was getting confused by people saying that using a lateinit was bad and that lazy ('by') was the only way.

We used ViewModelProvider before by viewModels() came. If you read the source code of viewModels() you can see that it is using ViewModelProvider to LAZILY initialize the ViewModel and nothing more, this is just a syntactic sugar for
private val viewModel: ViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider() }.
So If you want to initialize the ViewModel lazily use by viewModels(), if you want to initialize the ViewModel eagerly, use ViewModelProvider directly.

Ah, OK. I wasn't using VMs at all before the 'by' mechanism came along, so I was confused by all the people saying one method was equiv to another. So, by viewModels() is just syntactic sugar, just not for what I thought it was. I had been led to believe that lazy instantiation was the only way. This is now obviously not the case.

@flatCurrency , I told you the exact same thing as Alraj ...Please be more careful when reading documentation and people's answers

Definition of ViewModel as per Android docs:

A ViewModel is always created in association with a scope (an fragment
or an activity) and will be retained as long as the scope is alive.
E.g. if it is an Activity, until it is finished.
In other words, this means that a ViewModel will not be destroyed if
its owner is destroyed for a configuration change (e.g. rotation). The
new instance of the owner will just re-connected to the existing
ViewModel.
The purpose of the ViewModel is to acquire and keep the information
that is necessary for an Activity or a Fragment. The Activity or the
Fragment should be able to observe changes in the ViewModel.
ViewModels usually expose this information via LiveData or Android
Data Binding. You can also use any observability construct from you
favorite framework.
ViewModel's only responsibility is to manage the data for the UI. It
should never access your view hierarchy or hold a reference back to
the Activity or the Fragment.

The purpose of a ViewModelProvider is to optimize view model initialization. by activityViewModel() for fragments and by viewModels() for activities are simple shortcuts to writing lazy initializations of a viewmodel. It's the same as writing :
by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(myDesiredOwner, MyViewModelFactory(viewId))[YourViewModelClass::class.java]
    }

If you want to use the same view model for both your activity and fragment without initializing it 2ce replace myDesiredOwner with this in your activity class and with requireActivity() in your fragment class.

My View model contains nothing more than Flows and various observables. It knows nothing of fragments, applications, or view hierarchies. It is designed to be  completely self contained apart from a  dataStore reference. This Activity creates the reference to the dataStore and initialises the VM with that. Thereafter, nothing really interacts with the VM except my fragment(s). I created a factory class object containing just the dataStore reference and initialse the VM from that.

@flatCurrency you said: "In any case, I don't want to use the factory object in the Fragment because I don't have access to it, and don't want to end up coupling into the Fragment all the stuff that is managed by MainActivity, and I am expecting to use an already cached VM instance. " That's the job of the ViewModelProvider. You must write the code exactly as I provided. After I researched the issue a little it seems that by viewModels() and by activtyViewMoodels() always use the default factory

It is my experience that by viewModels() and by activityViewModels() /do/ use the factory passed as a lambda, when creating for the first time. However, I expected the lambda to be somehow 'associated' with the ViewModel, so that it can be invoked later, if it still hadn't been created by the time a naked by activityViewModels came along. This appears not to be the case: the lambda being the initialisation is only available when it is called that way. I don't fully understand all this stuff about passing code blocks as parameters so I may well have got it completely wrong.

I have now changed the initialisation model of my app. I now use the Factory mechanism to instantiate the /fragments/. In this way, my custom Fragment Factory has full view of which view models are to be injected into each fragment. In this way, I have Fragments that are not tied to a particular VM, and VMs that have no concept of the Fragments' existence. My ActivityMain is the only thing that bindsvtje two together.
